# Debugger multiple environment variables in C++ Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, debugging, environment-variables, visual-studio-2010

I got a very simple problem with the Visual Studio 2010 Professional C++ debugger when setting environment variables.

Described in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/kcw4dzyf.aspx 
Paragraph "Environment (Local Windows Debugger)".

I created a standard Win32 console project. I am setting the environment in project properties → *Debugger*:

```
TEST=asdf
OTHER=qwer
```

And printing the environment variables in the _tmain(...):

```
cout << "Hello " << getenv("TEST") << endl;
```

I would expect an out like:

```
"Hello asdf"
```

But instead I always get:

```
"Hello asdf OTHER=qwer"
```

How to fix this?!

---

It seems to be a DEU version bug.

I just filed a bug report:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727324/msvs10-c-deu-debugger-environment-variables-missing-linefeed#details

Comment: This doesn't repro for me - are you using VS 2010 with or without SP1? (I'm using SP1)

Comment: Got all updates. So this is SP1. Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel. I tested this on Professional and Ultimate on 2 different PCs so far. But always DEU edition.

Comment: This data gets stored in the `*.vcxproj.user` file - take a look in there and see what's delimiting the strings - mine has 0x0a chars between the strings.

Comment: yeah, line feed makes sense. there it is: <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>BLA="asdf" BLO="asdfwqe"</LocalDebuggerEnvironment> no delimiter. but if i paste <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>BLA="asdf"0x0aBLO="asdfwqe"</LocalDebuggerEnvironment> it doesnt make a change. so this is a bug in deu version?

Comment: Just to be clear - there's a single byte in the ``vcxproj.user` file that has the numeric value 0x0a (ie, it's a linefeed character), right? I'd be very surprised if this is a bug because of using the DEU edition, but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: well, a buddy tested this at work (EN_Version) which works. he just tested this at home (DEU_Version) which fails. crappy bug 8[

Comment: please post that on Microsoft's connect.microsoft.com site so there's some hope it'll be fixed in VS 11.

Comment: same on visual studio 2019 community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution so far:

Considering your example:

```
TEST=asdf
OTHER=qwer
```

Edit the `.vcxproj` adding inside `<Project>`:

```
  <Project .... >
  ...

  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
  <TEST>asdf</TEST>
  <OTHER>qwer</OTHER>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...
  </Project>
```

You can also add this on a `*.vcxproj.user` or a `*.props` file as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Running into a similar problem feeding this property programmatically, I bumped into this [github file](https://github.com/ENikS/OpenSSL-MSBuild/blob/master/debugger.xml). The separator is `"&#xA;"` in xml format, a.k.a. line feed. Using Environment.Newline solved the issue in dot net.

In interactive mode within the GUI, you want to click the edit button and use the rerun key to split your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to separate the environment variables with semicolons or some other kind of delimiter? It seems like `TEST` is getting assigned to `asdf OTHER=qwer`, not just `asdf`.

Comment: yes, "TEST" is obviously assigned to "asdf OTHER=qwer". i tested all delimiters i could image, but none of them fixed it.