# How come Visual Studio can't find my header even though it has been specified in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

So here is what my project looks like, for reference:

```
+ <root>
  + build
  + inc
    + libsm64
      + libsm64.hpp
  + src
    + libsm64.cpp
    + CMakeLists.txt
  + CMakeLists.txt
```

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(libsm64)

# add source.
add_subdirectory(src)
```

and the `CMakeLists.txt` for `/src`:

```
add_library(libsm64 libsm64.cpp ../inc/libsm64/libsm64.hpp)
target_include_directories(libsm64 PRIVATE ../inc)
```

Both Visual Studio 2019 and VSCode will give me an error in `libsm64.cpp` saying that it cannot open `libsm64/libsm64.hpp`. Why?

EDIT: Even if I replace the relative directory references with absolute references i.e. `${libsm64_PROJECT_DIR}/inc/libsm64/libsm64.hpp` it won't work.

Comment: In Visual Studio look at your Include directories in your project settings to see what was added.

Comment: It doesn't have a .sln file, it was created using visual studio's cmake integration. Should I use cmake to generate a .sln?

Comment: I have CMake generate Visual Studio project files always.

Comment: I believe the error has nothing to do with `${libsm64_PROJECT_DIR}/inc/libsm64/libsm64.hpp` or `add_library(libsm64 libsm64.cpp ../inc/libsm64/libsm64.hpp)`

Comment: Wait a minute is ***saying that it cannot open libsm64/libsm64.hpp.*** a compile error? or you can't open the file in the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232426/how-to-make-relative-file-path-work-in-visual-studio-using-cmake) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864259/how-to-set-working-directory-for-visual-studio-2017-rc-cmake-project).

You want to add a `currentDir` entry, sorta like this:

```
"currentDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
```

Visual Studio apparently ain't that smart.