# CMake set different Debug and Release working directories in Visual Studio

Tags: cmake

Is there a possibility to set different working directories ([VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950887/does-cmake-offer-a-method-to-set-the-working-directory-for-a-given-build-system/24004878)) for `Debug` and `Release` builds in a CMake generated Visual Studio project?

If I write

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_BIN} PROPERTIES 
    VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Debug")
```

Selecting *Project Properties > Debugging > Working Directory* will display

> C:/Users/Alexandru/Documents/MyProject/Build/Debug

for both `Debug` and `Release` configurations, but I want

> C:/Users/Alexandru/Documents/MyProject/Build/Release

for the `Release` configuration.

I also tried setting `VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` and `VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY_RELEASE` but it seems these properties don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no configuration specific properties and generator expressions like `$<CONFIG>` don't work (tested it with `VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY`to no avail), you can still use VS variables:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_BIN} PROPERTIES 
    VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$(Configuration)")
```

Comment: Where can I put this so that it works. I put this at the beginning (after project(name)...) of the CMake.txt file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @123iamking The above command changes a library or executable target's properties. To have the target in question known, it has to come in your `CMakeLists.txt` after that target is defined. CMake does not support forward declarations of target properties. Sometimes there are global variables available that define any upcoming target's defaults, but not is this particular case.

Comment: Can you make a simple CMake that make a project that has working directory in the bin folder, Please? :) I'm fairly new to CMake. Thank you very much.