# Set Visual Studio debugger working directory to executable output directory in CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Visual Studio's debugger's default working directory is `$(ProjectDir)`.

What I really want is it to be set to `$(TargetDir)` (where the `.exe` I am running is located).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950887/does-cmake-offer-a-method-to-set-the-working-directory-for-a-given-build-system) provides the correct syntax, so I tried the following:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
  set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BUILD_DIR}/Debug)
endif()
```

However this hard-codes `Debug`, which I don't like.

I tried `$<CONFIG>` at the end but that was invalid in Visual Studio (the expression is not evaluated).

I also tried `$(TargetDir)`, but that doesn't work. *But* if I manually delete the variable `$(TargetDir)` and paste it back in, it works.

How can I set the debugger working directory to the executable output directory without hard-coding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting the debugger working directory as follows:

```
set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR})
```

[`CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR.html) resolves to the build variable, which provides the current target configuration in Visual Studio.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It sets the working directory to CMakes source folder.