# Adding command line arguments to project

Tags: cmake

My question is somewhat similar to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998186) but not the same.

I created a `HelloWorld` program with the following:

```
add_executable( HelloWorld ${SRC} )
```

When I generate a project file (for example a Visual Studio .sln file, or an XCode .xcodeproj file). I want to hit the run button and pass in some command line arguments to `HelloWorld` when it executes the program, like the following:

```
./HelloWorld --gtest_filter=Test_Cases1*
```

Also see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697299/) for how this is done in Visual Studio.

Is it possible to do this in CMakeList file? If not, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer was written before CMake 3.13 was released, so it's now outdated. There is an [answer showing solution with CMake 3.13+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264858/1782465) also available.

---

CMake 3.12 and below has no built-in support for this. The reason is that the settings from the `Debugging` tab of Visual Studio Project properties are not stored in the project file (`.vc[x]proj`), but in a user-and-machine-specific `.user` file, and CMake does not generate these.

You can code it yourself in CMake (I did that for our framework at work). The file is just XML, so you can pre-populate it according to your needs. Its structure is pretty easy to understand. The command-line arguments for the program being debugged are stored in the `CommandArguments` attribute inside a `<DebugSettings>` XML element (nested in `<Configurations><Configuration>`), for example.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as long as you are using CMake >= 3.13.0. See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264858/2196304)

Answer (score 39):

Why so complicated? VS and CMake support this out of the box as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/#debug-code).
Open the CMakeLists.txt file in VS, and open the "Debug and launch settings" (e.g. via the "CMake" menu or via right-click in the "Solution Explorer". E.g.:

[image]

Add your program arguments to "args" in the file "launch.vs.json" which pops up.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "tests\\hellotest",
      "name": "tests\\hellotest with args",
      "args": ["argument after argument"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is most likely IDE specific as others have pointed out. It may have work in VS but not in other IDEs? Do you have a chance to test this out in Xcode for example?

Comment: VS express does not support this

Comment: This seems to be the best solution when working with `Visual Studio` and `CMake`, thanks for sharing this.

Comment: it doesn't work in my case (visual studio 2019)

Comment: @RaulLuna In VS2019 16.11, (Top menu) Debug -> Debug and Launch Settings for <current project name> . Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grryQ.png

Comment: not worked in vs2022

Comment: @alexcornejo in VS2022 it's labelled "Open Debug and Launch Settings"

Answer (score 19):

[CMake 3.13.0](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/milestones/26) looks like it will [add support](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2150) for this in the form of the following target properties:

- `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS` - Sets the local debugger command line arguments for Visual Studio C++ targets.
- `VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT` - Sets the local debugger environment for Visual Studio C++ targets.

It extends use with these commands, available since CMake 3.12:

- `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND` - Sets the local debugger command for Visual Studio C++ targets.
- `VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY` - Sets the local debugger working directory for Visual Studio C++ targets.

Comment: How do we use these?

Comment: with set_target_properties command - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html#set-target-properties:
`set_target_properties(HelloWorld 
  PROPERTIES
    VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS "--gtest_filter=Test_Cases1*"`

Answer (score 2):

A solution for `Visual Studio 2022` is clicking on the `Debug` menu bar item and then selecting `Debug and Launch Settings for <Project Name>`:

[image]

In the following `launch.vs.json` that opens, you can add your arguments at the bottom:

[image]

Now, when you start debugging using that profile, your desired command line arguments are passed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the case you want to add `E:\dev\IfcPL\examples\Trassierung.ifc` as an argument to a debug build project in Visual Studio 2017:

*project.vcxproj.user.in*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>E:\dev\IfcPL\examples\Trassierung.ifc</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

*CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp) 
configure_file(project.vcxproj.user.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/HelloWorld.vcxproj.user)
```

Answer (score -2):

Not a CMake trick. You can do this to set default `args` for debug builds:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{   const char* command = argv[1];
    if(argc < 2)
    {             
#ifdef _DEBUG
        command="hello";
#else
        Usage();
        return 1;
#endif
    }

[ process command arg... ]
```

Comment: This is not a bad idea, and completely independent of any build environment (well, as long as it sets _DEBUG).

Comment: But it does not work when the argument must be different for each developer.

Comment: Before doing this, I would prefer implementing a config file of some kind. Avoids recompiling every time the command line arguments change.